# Bibliography as section in LaTeX / BibTeX

Tags: latex, bibtex

I'm writing a short document using sections rather than chapters as the top-level (documentclass report). However,

```
\bibliographystyle{amsplain}
\bibliography{general}
```

causes the bibliography to be inserted as a chapter rather than a section. Is there any way to change this?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

By default, the `report` document class uses `\chapter` as the bibliography heading level.  In contrast, the `article` document class uses `\section` as the bibliography heading level.  If you're not using `\chapter` anywhere in your document, you might want to use the `article` class instead.

If you really want to use the `report` class, you'll need to redefine the `thebibliography` environment to use `\section` instead of `\chapter`.  In the preamble of your document (after the `\documentclass` line but before the `\begin{document}` line, insert the following:

```
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]
     {\section*{\bibname}% <-- this line was changed from \chapter* to \section*
      \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\bibname}{\MakeUppercase\bibname}%
      \list{\@biblabel{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
           {\settowidth\labelwidth{\@biblabel{#1}}%
            \leftmargin\labelwidth
            \advance\leftmargin\labelsep
            \@openbib@code
            \usecounter{enumiv}%
            \let\p@enumiv\@empty
            \renewcommand\theenumiv{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
      \sloppy
      \clubpenalty4000
      \@clubpenalty \clubpenalty
      \widowpenalty4000%
      \sfcode`\.\@m}
     {\def\@noitemerr
       {\@latex@warning{Empty `thebibliography' environment}}%
      \endlist}
\makeatother
```

Now your bibliography will have a `\section` heading instead of a `\chapter` heading.

Note that if you load any special bibliography packages, you might want to put this code *before* those packages are loaded (so you don't overwrite their work).

Comment: Not using any special packages. Thanks for the code, and for the article suggestion!

Comment: Thanks for the code. Works nicely. However, with this modification, the bibliography would disappear from the bookmark.

Comment: Thanks for this great code! I needed to include a bibliography as a subsubsection and the format of the bibliography header and the format of the header changed without a problem. However, I also use the fancyheadr package it still puts the bibliography as a section into the header, altough it is supposed to be a subsubsection... Is there also fix for that?

Comment: @Luise That's a result of the `\@mkboth` line. If you remove that line, it should leave the running heads unmolested. I probably should've modified that originally when changing `\chapter*` to `\section*`.

Answer (score 11):

Look at the package [tocibind](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tocbibind);

```
\usepackage[numbib,notlof,notlot,nottoc]{tocbibind}
```

`numbib` ensures the Bibliography gets numbered, while the `not*`-options disables showing the List of Figures, Tables and the TOC itself, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I also changed @godbyk's solution to include the section number.

@godbyk's line:

```
{\section*{\bibname}% <-- this line was changed from \chapter* to \section*
```

My line:

```
{\section{\bibname}% <-- this line was changed from \chapter* to \section
```

Answer (score 0):

For having references at the chapter level, one can use:

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{References}
```

To have them at the section level, one can use:

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{References}
```