# Which command is used by bibtex to create the bibliography header?

Tags: latex, bibtex

I'm using multibib to create a list of articles in an appendix.

```
%Preamble...
%Create new macros for citation in "lit" group
\newcites{lit}{My list of articles}

%The appendix
\appendix
\chapter{My list of articles}
%Force use of citations
\nocitelit{ref01}
...
\nocitelit{refNN}
%Stop clear double page
\newcommand{\foo}{}
\let\cleardoublepage\foo
%Will print bib heading
\bibliographylit{myrefs}
```

The problems I ran into was that I wish to replace the automatic chapter heading generated by the `\bibliographylit` command (which in turn uses bibtex, I guess) with a NULL command so that I can use my own appendix chapter heading. I could remove the double page clearing by using the command:

```
\newcommand{\foo}{}
\let\cleardoublepage\foo
```

And I wish to do the same but with the whole chapter heading. Redefining `\chapter` left me with a * in the place of the chapter.

As suggested here: [Bibliography as section in LaTeX / BibTeX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1037905/bibliography-as-section-in-latex-bibtex)
this didn't work:
http://www.flakery.org/search/show/568
(`\bibsection` is undefined)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, my understanding of `\renewcommand` was lacking. Adding two arguments as:

```
\renewcommand{\chapter}[2]{}
```

Everything works!

**Edit:** I've also learned that you can "scope" the redefintion, so to leave \chapter command untouched after this bibliography I do:

```
\chapter{Appendix with references}
{ %Disable chapter command
\renewcommand{\chapter}[2]{}
\bibliography{myrefs}
}
```

Pretty sweet!