# Latex Bibtex Bibliography without new Chapter

Tags: reference, latex, bibtex

I'd like Bibtex to not start a new page, when printing the references. Why? I am using the package quotchap to print those nice big numbers on the right site for each new chapter and I want the references too to have such a big number. Another way bould be to tell Bibtex simply to make the references a chapter, but I don't know how to do either of it.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Impossible to help without a [minimal working example](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/minexample/index.html). A better place to ask would be TeX.SE.

Answer (score 0):

#### Reference (Bibtex) on the same page:

I suppose you are using a certain template? Because in the normal case, the references (using Bibtex) do not start automatically on a new page. An example of what I am using:

```
\bibliographystyle{acm}
\bibliography{References}
```

Also make sure that you have no `\newpage` or likewise commands right before your bibliography.

#### Changing references to separate chapter

If you use the `report` class instead of the `article` class Latex handles the references/bibliography as a chapter heading level, while in an `article` the heading is that of a section.

#### Changing the heading by hand to mimic a chapter heading

Of course it is not always possible to change the `report` class. In that case you are still not lost. You could change the specific reference heading by adding some code in the preamble. Therefore check this
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1037905/bibliography-as-section-in-latex-bibtex).

Another possibility is to change the style of the numberless sections, using the `titlesec` package. Note that this also affects the title format of  for example the table of contents. An example of how I did that in the past:

```
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{name=\section, **numberless**}                     
    {\Large\sf\raggedright}                 
    {}{0mm}                     
    {\MakeUppercase}                        
    [\titlerule]                            
\titlespacing*{name=\section, numberless}{0mm}{10mm}{10mm}
```